# Using Jasmine to `spyOn` a function in a (different) closure

Tags: jasmine, closures, browserify, require, spyon

We're using `require` and Browserify, so single-function modules are imported like this:

```
var loadJson = require('../loadJson');
```

and used like this:

```
x = loadJson(url);
```

I'd like to `spyOn` that loadJson function, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

It's not a global function, so this doesn't work:

```
spyOn(window, 'loadJson')
```

It's not a local function, so this doesn't work:

```
loadJson = createSpy('loadJsonSpy', loadJson).and.callThrough();
```

When I `require` the module into my Jasmine spec, the function is visible inside that closure, but that's not the same closure as the other module which are actually using `loadJson` for real.

[image]

So in short, I *think* it's not possibly to use `spyOn` in this case - is that correct? Any creative workarounds?

Comment: Oh. http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: That link is for testing private functions. ```loadJson``` is not a private function in your case.

Comment: Are you sure? It's specifically about testing functions within closures - it just calls them "private functions".

Comment: ```function closureOne(){function privA(){} return function pubB(){}} function closureTwo(){var refOfB = closureOne()}```
In this example ```privA()``` is private. ```pubB()``` is public. In ```cloureTwo()```, by referencing ```pubB``` to ```refOfB```(a closure private variable) does not make ```pubB``` a private function.

Comment: ```pubB``` is similar to ```loadJson``` in you case.

Comment: Did my answer work? How did you solve this??

Answer (score 0):

If `loadJson` is singleton, then you can do this.

```
var functionsToSpyOn = {loadJson: loadJson}
spyOn(functionsToSpyOn, 'loadJson')
```

This is the workaround I used when I had the same problem.